# Is Project Titan (Facebook email app) going to be a game changer from a programmers perspective?

Tags: social-networks, email, web-services

Is Project Titan (Facebook email app) going to be a game changer from a programmers perspective?

Although some details are still scarce, the internet is slowly learning more about this new software. From the perspective of a programmer, what if any functionality do you think this will bring to the mass communications sector of internet use? Will it in anyway be a "game changer" from the existing layer of highly successful web based email clients (such as hotmail, gmail, yahoo mail, etc)

I'm interested if anyone thinks email fundamentally needs to change other than to add more "connectedness" to other sources of data such as social media profiles.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: It's not off-topic. The question states.. "from the perspective of a programmer" it definately doesn't belong on SO and Im not interested in putting this type of question on the web apps site.

Comment: Just putting "from a programmers perspective" after a question doesn't make it properly programming related.  If it did you could have "what's the best dinosaur from a programmers perspective".

Comment: @Jon Hopkins, good point Jon, but I think you also need to consider the context and intent of the question. In this case the question was not just "what is [X] from a programmers perspective" it was a serious technical question about the implications of change on a fundemental software technology (email) that 100,000's programmers work with everyday. If something is potentially "game changing" then I think that thing is definately of interest and applicable to programmers. While what you say might hold true in general, I don't think it applies to this specific question.

Comment: @Anonymous Type - maybe but it's really just a call for speculation based an limited facts. I think the objection is a hybrid of off-topic (because at this point Titan isn't a developer platform) and not a real question because of the speculative element.

Comment: Yes I see your point, however as more facts about titan come to light and it is opened up (via API) then the speculation angle is replaced by factual information on the platform. I'm not really asking answerers to speculate on "what the game changing nature of the platform will be" that will of cause be revealed (or not) in due time. I'm asking do you think based on the available data that it will/will not be game changing. I think the answer to date covers that quite well, which is why I accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More integration inside of Facebook may make Facebook users stay inside the Facebook site more (and more page views means more advertising dollars in Facebook's pockets).  People who are e-mailed from Facebook but who don't already have an account may be encouraged to get one by their peers.  However, there are many many people who use email but do not use Facebook and are not interested in social networking.  I don't see there being much of a change.  Google Wave attempted to extend email but failed (it looked like a great concept but was confusing for users, and ultimately abandoned by Google); Microsoft Lync and Google Buzz attempt to integrate social networking and email, but I only see that as being useful for people who really want to use it for social networking.